# Free() function causes program to crash

Tags: c

I am currently trying to free up allocated memory, however by doing so it causes the program to crash. I am new to C and programming in general, and would be great to receive help with issue and any further issues that may stem from my inexperience.

```
Pool* allocatePool(int x);
void freePool(Pool* pool);
void store(Pool* pool, int offset, int size, void *object);

typedef struct _POOL
{
    int size;
    void* memory;
} Pool;

int main()
{
    printf("enter the number of bytes you want to allocate//>\n");
    int x;
    Pool* p;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    p=allocatePool(x);
    freePool(p);
    return 0;
}

/* Allocate a memory pool of size n bytes from system memory (i.e., via malloc()) and return a pointer to the filled data Pool structure */

Pool* allocatePool(int x)
{
    static Pool p;
    p.size = x;

    p.memory = malloc(x);
    printf("%p\n", &p);

    return &p;//return the address of the Pool
}

/* Free a memory pool allocated through allocatePool(int) */
void freePool(Pool* pool) 
{
    free(pool);
    printf("%p\n", &pool);
}
```

Comment: You must `free` the same memory that you have allocated. You `malloc` to `p.memory`, but you `free(&p)`, which isn't memory alocated o the heap at all, but the address of a static object.

Comment: It is never `free()` function which causes the program to crash. It is a bug in your code which causes the program to crash.

Comment: @SergeyA _Never_ is a bit strong. It's a bit like saying you'll never be struck by lightning. Sure it's not very likely, but it's not like there aren't any buggy implementations of malloc/free _somewhere_.

Comment: @Cubic, `-fpedantic` :)

Comment: About this kind of error: Use the system's tools to help you here. Microsoft's Visual Studio in Debug mode will crash your program fairly informatively. In Linux run your program with "valgrind" which will report the bad free() call.

Comment: And if you're using GCC with the warning options it has a warning for this. Ironically, the warning only triggers when compiled with optimization. Inlining, specifically.
`gcc -O2 -Wall -W bad-free-test.c 
bad-free-test.c: In function ‘main’:
bad-free-test.c:17:2: warning: attempt to free a non-heap object ‘pool’ [-Wfree-nonheap-object]
  free(pool);
`

Answer (score 3):

You must free the same memory that you have allocated. here:

```
p.memory = malloc(x);
```

you allocate `x` bytes to `p.memory`. That means that here:

```
free(pool);
printf("%p\n", &pool);
```

you should free the same memory. You try to `free` the pool object instead, but that isn't allocated on the heap. In your implementation, it is a static object that holds the single pool. Trying to `free` memory that wasn't allocated on the heap is undefined behaviour, in yourcase a crash.

The code above also shows another misconception about `free`: It doesn't change the handle to the allocated memory. It only marks the previously allocated bytes as usable again. Your program must guard against accessing memory through the pointer whose memory you have `free`d.

Also, `&pool` is not the address of the pool object, but the address of the local pointer variable `pool`.

To fix your crash, change your function to:

```
void freePool(Pool *pool) 
{
    if (pool) free(pool->memory);
}
```

Comment: Still won't solve the problem, because p in main is now pointing to memory that is no longer valid.

Comment: Wrong @FredK, he returns address of **static** Pool to the main and pass it to freePool... Nothing's wrong here.

Comment: Ah - missed the "static" declaration. Still not a good design; there will be a memory leak if he calls allocatePool() a second time without first freeing p,memory.

Comment: @FredK: Yes, the design is poor; `allocatePool` suggests that you can get many pools. The OP's grasp of pointers and allocation is not very good yet, so that's the first thing to fix here.